# How do I access the 360 guide while on XB1?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, backwards-compatibility

With Rare Replay, it includes the 360 versions of some games to "show off" the Backwards compatibility in action. I can get 360 style notifications and achievements, but pressing the xbox button brings me to the XB1's home instead.

How do I get the 360 guide to show up? It was advertised as being able to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call upon the Xbox 360 guide by pressing both, simultaneously, the View and Menu buttons (the new Start and Back buttons). See here for a [controller layout reference](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/accessories/xbox-one-wireless-controller).

Reference: [Xbox One Backwards Compatibility FAQ](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/system/compatibility-with-xbox-360-faq)

Comment: I am logged in. it gives "Group not found". Probably because I'm not part of the preview program